# Why does the presence or absence of the trim() function make a difference IN SAS?

Tags: sas

In the code below, why does the presence or absence of the trim() function makes a difference of results in Columns B and C?

```
data work.ironman ; 
length a $ 10 ;
input a $ @@; 
cards ;
i am iron man
; 
run ; 
proc print ; run ;

/* Logic error */
data work.to_thanos  ; 
set work.ironman ; 
length b $100 ; 
retain b "Hey Thanos!" ; output ;
do i = a ; 
c = b || " " || i ; output ; /* <- This part makes logic error.. */
b = c ; output ;  
end ; 
run ; 
proc print ; run ;

/* Correct Results */
data work.to_thanos  ; 
set work.ironman ; 
length b $100 ; 
retain b "Hey Thanos!" ; output ;
do i = a ; 
c = trim(b) || " " || i ; output ; /* <- This part which contains trim() function makes correct results */
b = c ; output ;  
end ; 
run ; 
proc print ; run ;
```

Below are the results of executing the above code.

Thank you for your answer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isCYc.png)

Comment: `trim()` is a function to remove the trailing blanks from a character string. If you connect variable `b` and `i` without `trim()`, you are actually connect 'Hey Thanos!' 
 and 89 trailing spaces and i, where 89 is variable length of `b` minus length of content of `b`.

Comment: It does not make much sense to have a DO loop that iterates over a list of only one value.  Why not just replace it with an assignment statement and remove the now unneeded END statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS has two variable types.  Floating point numbers and fixed length character strings. If the string stored into a character variable is shorter then its defined length the rest of the variable is filled with spaces. If the string is longer than the variables defined length the extra characters are lost. If you concatenate variables without first removing the trailing spaces they become part of the resulting string.

You define A as length $10 and B as length $100, but leave it up to SAS to **guess** how to define I and C. Since I is initialized to the value of A SAS will guess it should be defined as length $10 also.  Since C is defined as the concatenation of B and I and string of length 1 SAS will guess you wanted it to be of length $111.

In your final assignment of C into B the last 11 characters of C (which includes the 10 characters of A as copied via I) will not fit into the 100 bytes of B  and so are lost.

SAS now has a whole series of CAT..() functions that make it a little easier to concatenate values.  Looks like you want the CATX() function.

```
data step1 ; 
  set ironman ; 
  length b $100 ; 
  retain b "Hey Thanos!" ; 
  b = catx(' ',b,a);
run;
```

Result

```
Obs    a       b

 1     i       Hey Thanos! i
 2     am      Hey Thanos! i am
 3     iron    Hey Thanos! i am iron
 4     man     Hey Thanos! i am iron man
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tom. I understood your answer. I missed the concept related to the length of the variable. Thank you once again for your answer. My English is not very good, so please understand.